# bootstrap popover lies under cells in fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar with bootstrap popovers. The goal is to append a form for adding new event inside the popovers. The code does make the popover appears above the cells, however, on clicking the popovers, the cells underneath it are selected rather than the popovers themselves.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: height,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ){
            if (view.name=='month'){
            $(this).children().popover({
        placement: 'right',
        content: function() {return $("#popover-content").html();},
html : true, container: 'body'
    });
    $('.popover.in').remove();
    $(this).children().popover('show');
..........
```

and html

```
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
<form>
    <input id="easyeventtitle" />
  </form>
</div>
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qr2R.png)

I have tried `z-index` to popovers, instead, they do not appear at all!

Please help! Thank you for your time!

**Edit**: [here is the link to test it](http://ec2-50-112-16-230.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test)

Comment: Not able to replicate the issue here? http://jsfiddle.net/N4vBU/

Comment: @PSL I have put up the link to my page. on jsfiddle, there is an extra issue, although i can select the popovers, the triggers, i.e. the table cells can only fire up the popovers once. After deselecting, selecting the table cells result popovers flashing instead of appearing.

Comment: Why you are appending it to that td, what happens when you provide `container:'body'` for popover like this http://jsfiddle.net/QCGj2/ Since you are appending it inside td. click event on the popover bubbles up to the click event on the td which is full calendar day click and it created popover for the other cell.

Comment: @PSL The reason I append it to div is because when appending to td, even with "container:'body'", the cell width still alters. Strange thing, I copied the code on jsfiddle to a new page, with reference, the table size alters, but not on jsfiddle.

Comment: Probably the version of bootstrap on the fiddle, matters change it to what you are using and see if you can replicate it in the fiddle.

Comment: @PSL after playing with fiddle, the problem is solved after I changed my bootstrap.min.js to an online source. Actually it's the very same version 2.3.2, and I was just using local file. How would that cause the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({        
   header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
   },
  events: '/events.json',
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
  dayClick: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {            
    $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'right',
                title: function() {
                    return $("#popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function() {
                    return $("#popover-content").html();
                },
                html: true,
                container: 'body'
            });
    $(this).popover('toggle');
  }    
 });
});
```

Comment: Well actually this does not works properly. Event if I put tabindex=".." attribute for cross-browser compatibility (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), left click is not working, only showing with right click.

Unfortunately I haven't found any other solution so far, but to "mimic" the "others" clicks by calling to destroy the all popovers on body click event

Comment: If you can show me your script than i can help you.